# VBA - Maintain cell formula integrity

Tags: vba, excel-formula, excel-r1c1-notation

I am having a difficult time inputting an `Indirect` formula into my code.  I understand that I can use a `FormulaR1C1`, however that creates a formula in the cell that is fairly static and is not too kind when adding rows after I run my code.  I'd like my code to be something like this in-cell formula `=SUM(L99:INDIRECT("R[-1]C",0))`, which resides in cell `L106`.

[image: Formula Screenshot]

Below is my code as well as my attempt at creating the above formula.  Thanks!

```
   Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet: Set s1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

   With s1

        'What the current formula is
        .Cells(rwCnt, abRng.Column).Offset(4, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[0]C[-5],R[0]C[-2])"
        .Cells(rwCnt, abRng.Column).Offset(11, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R[-7]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])"

        'My attempt
        .Cells(rwCnt, abRng.Column).Offset(11, 6).Formula = "=sum(" & .Cells(rwCnt, abRng.Column).Offset(4, 6) _
            & ":INDIRECT(""R[-1]C"", 0))"

   End With
```

Comment: `.Cells(rwCnt, abRng.Column).Offset(4, 6) ` i think this will be returning the value in the cell, where you need the address of it, for example cells(1,1) would return a value, where cells(1,1).address would return $A$1

Comment: I love the simple answers!  That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Cells(rwCnt, abRng.Column).Offset(4, 6)` i think this will be returning the value in the cell, where you need the address of it

For example `cells(1,1)` would return a value, where `cells(1,1).address` would return `$A$1`